# Streaming an MP3 cuts off last 1-2 seconds of audio

Tags: php, apache, audio, mp3, audio-streaming

I've searched and googled for quite a bit with nothing really able to resolve my issue.

I have an mp3 file on my server that I need to serve to my end users so they can hear the recording and verify that it's correct. The problem is that when listening, the browser (Safari and Chrome at least) will cut off the last 1-2 seconds of a recording. (which is not very helpful.

Stuff I've tried already.

- Downloaded the file directly from the server, and it DOES play
  correctly.
- Verified the mime type of the browser mp3 file using `file` and it's audio/mpeg; charset=binary
- Downloaded the file through the browser and the file and
  my server file are the exact same bytes. The files show that (for
  instance) they are 9 seconds long, but when I play it in the browser
  it shows the file is only 7 seconds long.
- Messed around with the headers of the file with no luck.

  ```
  header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg; charset=binary");
  header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"{$filename}\"");
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  header("Content-Length: ". filesize($file_path));
  readfile($file_path);
  ```

I've pretty much narrowed down the problem to something that happens from calling the file on my server to bringing it to my browser. The stuff I've tried hasn't really helped. One of my requirements is that I have to have this protected and out of a public directory, so I have to serve it through PHP as the user has to be authenticated before they can play the file. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Here's some versions if it helps.

```
CentOS 7.4.1708
Apache 2.4.6
PHP 5.6.30
Chrome Version 60.0.3112.113
Safari Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)
```

**Update**

```
The data from the main wav file I'm receiving is the following
Duration: 00:09
Audio Channels: 1
Sample Rate: 8,000
Bits Per Sample: 16
```

Comment: What MP3 encoder are you using for recording? Is it possible the encoder does it wrong? Are you using **constant** bitrate (if not then try it)? Can you make a short (9 seconds?) file for analysis? Sample file can even be just ambient noise or non audible content since we only want to check duration issues vs bytes content...

Comment: So I actually receive the file as a wav, then convert it to an MP3 using ffmpeg. When I convert it, I use the following command `ffmpeg -i input.wav -vn -ac 2 -ar 8000 -ab 32k -f mp3 output.mp3` When I convert it and directly download the file from the server using scp, the wav and the mp3 match perfectly. The problem is somewhere between my server serving the file and me receiving it in the browser.

Comment: @n0nag0n What makes you think the issue has to do between your server and receiving it in the browser?  It's very likely that if you just drag that local file to your browser, you'll reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: I just drug the mp3 file I directly downloaded onto my browser and it sounded perfect, without anything getting cut off.

Comment: I'm sorry you had to see me drug an mp3 file XD

Answer (score 1):

A lot of audio players, particularly around MP3, are quite buggy.  They'll use things like fixed-size buffers.  Also, you should know that with MP3 it isn't possible to precisely set seek points without decoding the whole file.  There are a lot of hacks/tricks around file length, byte offsets, and guessing, but that's about it.  Basically, you can't ever expect timing to be correct with lossy encoded audio that has no container or bitstream format indicating what time it is.  I do think it's reasonable to have your file played completely through though.

You should also know that your sample rate is *extremely* low, as is your bitrate, particularly for using stereo audio.

There's probably a fixed-size buffer somewhere that's expecting say 8KB of data and it's getting a small fraction of that due to the low sample rate and bitrate.  This would be a player bug, and short of filing a bug report, there's nothing you can do about it directly.

Consider Opus?  You'll get much higher quality, and it's quite compatible.  Failing that, consider just using straight up PCM.

Comment: The reason for the low sample rate is I'm recording a response in a phone call, so the wav file I get back is only in the same bitrate. I'm just mimicking what I'm already receiving. Good ideas to try, I can try encoding with something else.

Comment: @n0nag0n Opus is great for voice.  But yeah, given the size and what not, I'd just send the regular WAV file!

Comment: Yeah, it's a difference of a filesize that 139kb vs 31kb. A lot less waiting on the client side to get it.

Comment: @n0nag0n I suppose it might be different for your clients and where you're located, but at least in the US, even on mediocre 3G cell providers, the difference there isn't much unless you're going to be doing that hundreds of times.  Especially if the WAV actually works and gives you the best client compatibility.

Comment: Well that's part of the trouble, I couldn't get the WAV file to play in the browser, so I converted it to MP3, and now it works, just loses the last 1-2 seconds when it comes through the browser.

Comment: @n0nag0n WAV is a relatively simple format... you can parse the header structure and dump it into buffers with the Web Audio API.  I've done this in the past and it works well... I don't have code I can share with you unfortunately.  Start with Opus, see if that gets you where you want to be.